# how to upload my app to the play store with call log permission

Tags: android, permission-denied

I have an app that gets the caller Id and gives the user a message about any history call log for this caller and notes saved by the app about this caller( if the caller id is one of the phone contact )

but the app has been rejected by Google due to using Read Call Log permission , despite I have set the this  ( get caller id ) is the core function of the app .

any advice .. what should I do to let google accept the app

this a video for a screen record for the app

https://vimeo.com/381293256

looking to have a  solution

Comment: what is the full reason they reject it?

Comment: this is the context of thier massage ( Requested permissions do not match core functionality of the app
You declared Caller ID, spam detection, and /or spam blocking as the core functionality of your app. However, after review, we found that your app does not match the declared use case(s). Learn more about permitted uses and exceptions.
Please either:
• Make changes to your app so that it meets the requirements of the declared core functionality or,
• Select a use case that matches your app’s functionality)

Comment: they mentioned that the app doesn't match the core function that I declared

Comment: i have used Read Call log permission to get the caller id for devices with android version 9 and above

Comment: From video, I cannot see spam detection or spam blocking?

Comment: yes, it's just a caller id , although i have set a new case as just call id (without spam detection ) but they also rejected the app

Comment: So what is there reject message for the call id app?

Comment: the same that the permissions do not match the core function call id

Comment: what is the full reason?

Comment: thanks, @Blundell I have checked all of my emails from google play support and i send to them anther special use case, I will try now with call id special case , hope this will work

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: unfortunately not yet

Comment: @MaiAbuAjamieih Any new news here?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet